# How to set permission of Rolling File Appender through log4j.properties file

Tags: properties, permissions, log4j

I have log4j.properties file with
`log4j.appender.WD=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender log4j.appender.WD.File=${catalina.base}/logs/sample.log`

The file sample.log I want to set owner and user permission. When I am seeing it, everywhere they have told about giving permission when we are using log4j configuration using xml file. Can someone help me with how can I set the permission for log4j configuration inside properties file?

`log4j.appender.WD.rollingPolicy.setFilePermissions=766`

I tried doing this, not sure if this is the correct one

Answer (score 1):

## File Permissions Only Support For Log4j 2

```
appender.rolling.fileOwner = demo
appender.rolling.fileGroup = demo
appender.rolling.filePermissions = rw-rwx---
```

### Example - log4j2.properties

```
# https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html
# https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html
status = info
dest = err
name = PropertiesConfig

property.filename = ${catalina.base}/logs/rollingtest.log

# filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
# filter.threshold.level = debug

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
# appender.console.layout.pattern = %m%n
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n
# appender.console.filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
# appender.console.filter.threshold.level = error
# appender.console.filter.threshold.level = debug

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = ${filename}
appender.rolling.filePattern = ${catalina.base}/logs/test1-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 2
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=100KB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 5
appender.rolling.fileOwner = demo
appender.rolling.fileGroup = demo
appender.rolling.filePermissions = rw-rwx---

logger.rolling = debug, RollingFile
logger.rolling.name = org.example.Main
logger.rolling.additivity = false

# rootLogger = debug, STDOUT

# or using a grouping element:
rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```